# how to implode the following array for $val = explode(",".$number)

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [num] => 338975270
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [num] => 4542682328
    )
)
```

now i want to use implode function to get output like :

```
(338975270,4542682328)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should ..

```
echo "(".implode(',', array_map(function ($v){ return $v['num'];},$yourarray)).")";
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/138742)</kbd>

#### Explanation :

You can't directly use `implode()` on a MD array. So use an `array_map()` to grab all those values with **num** key and then subject that to your `implode()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
$result = implode(',',array_column($a,'num')));
```

Extract values and implode them